# Create local TypeScript package with types and functions defined in separate source files

Tags: typescript, npm, package.json

I am trying to learn `npm` and TypeScript.  My aim is to create a TypeScript package called `scrape-jobs` in one project and use it in another.  I want to keep my type definitions separate from my function definitions (in the source code) if at all possible.

After building my project, my `scrape-jobs` folder structure is as follows:

```
|   .eslintignore
|   .eslintrc
|   .prettierrc
|   package-lock.json
|   package.json
|   tsconfig.json
|   
+---build
|       functions.d.ts
|       functions.d.ts.map
|       functions.js
|       functions.js.map
|       types.d.ts
|       types.d.ts.map
|       types.js
|       types.js.map
|       
+---src
|       functions.ts
|       types.ts
```

As shown, the declaration files for my functions and types are now in two files: `functions.d.ts` and `types.d.ts`.  However, the `"types"` property in `package.json` only allows for a single value, so how can I specify both `*.d.ts` files to the consuming project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer with the help of a friend: to create a *third* file that simply exports the functions and types in the first two.  So I have now created `index.ts` that simply reads:

```
export { IScrapeJobs } from './types'
export { scrapeJobs } from './functions'
```

Both my `"main"` and my `"types"` properties in `package.json` are now set to `"./build/index"` and everything is working correctly.